# Node.JS Express - Original HTTP Request

Tags: node.js, http, web, server, request

Is there a way in Express to get the original HTTP request as it was prior to being parsed?

Like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: You can get [`req.rawHeaders`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#messagerawheaders) which is the headers, but not the first line.  Pieces of the first line are in `req.method`, `req.httpVersion`, `req.originalUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

See link below for a basic implementation which I used to implement a store-and-forward proxy. This uses the raw Node.js `http` module, but express.js extends the req/res objects, so it should be fully compatible:
https://github.com/rkaw92/edi-broker-poc/blob/df7d643ed07e8004eb7a93fcde580549872fe757/src/httpUtils.ts#L50